# get 5 row and transform into columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rows, stock

I have a dataset and what I want is. Lets say I am in the row with index 4, I want to get the past 4 candles and insert their values into the row which I am. Like this:

```
    open_close  close_open  open_high  open_low  close_high  close_low   close  out
0       0.0000      0.0000     0.0000    0.0002      0.0000     0.0002  0.6114    1
1      -0.0001      0.0001    -0.0002    0.0003     -0.0001     0.0004  0.6114    0
2      -0.0001      0.0001    -0.0002    0.0001     -0.0001     0.0002  0.6113    1
3       0.0001     -0.0001     0.0000    0.0003     -0.0001     0.0002  0.6114    1
4       0.0000      0.0000     0.0000    0.0002      0.0000     0.0002  0.6115    0
5       0.0002     -0.0002     0.0000    0.0002     -0.0002     0.0000  0.6113    1
6       0.0000      0.0000     0.0000    0.0002      0.0000     0.0002  0.6115    1
7       0.0000      0.0000    -0.0001    0.0002     -0.0001     0.0002  0.6115    1
8       0.0002     -0.0002     0.0000    0.0003     -0.0002     0.0001  0.6115    1
9       0.0001     -0.0001     0.0000    0.0003     -0.0001     0.0002  0.6117    1
```

SO it will be:

```
   open_close0   open_close1   open_close2   open_close3   open_close  close_open  open_high  open_low  close_high  close_low   close  out
4       0.0000       -0.0001       -0.0001        0.0001       0.0000      0.0000     0.0000    0.0002      0.0000     0.0002  0.6115    0
```

It follows the same logic for all rows, and I wanted to do this with all columns except the "out" column. Is there any function in pandas that facilitates this?

Comment: English please .

Comment: take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410312/how-to-create-a-lagged-data-structure-using-pandas-dataframe

Comment: sorry i already translated

Comment: thanks was that what i was looking for